# React state is undefined , even though console.log shows it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have researched other cases when the state was unidentified but I am still unsuccessfully trying to subtract data from UI actions that is in the format [{},{}...]. I have managed to add to the array , using this code, which in the same time also computes the total for the item (subTotal and products are props from a child component got through a callback function):

```
const updateTotalPriceAndUpdatePieChartData = (subTotal,product) => {
        //from here   
        setPieChartData([...pieChartData,{product,subTotal}])
        //until up, we handle what data we need for the pieChart
        setTotal(total => total + (Number.isFinite(subTotal) ? subTotal : 0))
        console.log("TOTAL WAS COMPUTED")
    }
```

And this is the state that holds the array:

```
const [pieChartData,setPieChartData]=React.useState([])
```

Yet when I try to delte an object from the state array (when an item is also deleted), I try the following :

```
const substractSubTotalAndSubstractTotalForPieChart = (subTotal,product,pieChartData) => {
    setTotal(total - subTotal)
    const lastPieChartData=pieChartData.filter(item => item !={subTotal,product})
    setPieChartData(lastPieChartData)
}
```

It says that `pieChartData` is unidentified. Could you please let me know what I can do?

Comment: Can you also show how are you calling the substractSubTotalAndSubstractTotalForPieChart method?

Comment: Yes , Im calling it in the child with a callback function ,like this: `<button onClick={() => { handleDeletion(); substractSubTotalAndSubstractTotalForPieChart(subTotal,product) }} value={subTotal}>Remove</button>`

Comment: @Rohan Agarwal I have just defined a new handler:`const getPieChartData=()=>{
        return pieChartData
    }`  and modified in substractSubTotalAndSubstractTotalForPieChart as `const lastPieChartData=getPieChartData().filter(item => item !={product,subTotal})` . I dont get the error of undefined anymore , but It still doesnt filter out the passed object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `substractSubTotalAndSubstractTotalForPieChart` method, there is a paramter `pieChartData`, but there is also a `state` with the **same name**. So what happens is inside the function `substractSubTotalAndSubstractTotalForPieChart's` scope, the parameter `pieChartData` is given preference rather than the state.

Hence in your method invocation, when you don't pass this parameter, the default value of an uninitialized parameter, i.e., undefined is used.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. I have initially tried **without**  passing the `pieChartData` as an argument to the method, yet it also didn't work , holding everything else the same. I have managed to avoid the `undefined` issue by defining a method that returns the 'pieChartData` state , yet when I try to filter over its outcome it is not change at all. Thanks a lot for the reply !

Comment: I see that you are trying to compare an entire object. This might be the issue. Try comparing the properties of both your objects in the filter. @АнастасияШалунова